# How to use JavaScript variables in Thymeleaf template

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have an ajax call

```
$.ajax({
        url: "/user/login",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify(user),
        success: function(result){
            
        }
    });
```

I want to access result variable in thymeleaf template like below

```
<li th:if="${result}" class="nav-item for-tab-mobile ">
   
</li>
```

Comment: It's not clear what you want to accomplish here.  Have you read through the [Thymeleaf docs on JavaScript inlining](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#javascript-inlining)?

Comment: In case this is a misunderstanding: Thymeleaf only exists on the server. Its purpose is to remove itself from your templates (and replace itself with HTML - and also with JS variables). You therefore cannot submit an ajax request from a web page (which no longer contains Thymeleaf) and expect the `success` result to be handled by Thymeleaf _in the web page_.